# Why does this not give a type error?

Tags: scala, types

I would expect this to give me a type error since `(String, String)` in the `else` case is not `Pair`.

```
case class Pair(x: String, y: String)

val value = Console.readLine.toBoolean

val Pair(x, y) =
  if (value) Pair("foo", "bar")
  else false
```

Instead, if I enter false, I get the following error at run time.

```
scala.MatchError: (foo,bar) (of class scala.Tuple2)
```

I suppose the deconstruction is just sugar for assigning the result to a variable of type `Any` and then matching on it, but it seems unfortunate that Scala lets this fly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you compile this code with `scalac -print` you see, what happens. As you correctly supposed, it is just syntactic sugar for a pattern matching. Actually your case class extends Product, which also is a superclass of Tuple2 and that is wh your code compiles. Your value gets assigned to a variable of type Product:

```
val temp6: Product = if (value)
      new Main$Pair("foo", "bar")
    else
      new Tuple2("foo", "bar");
```

And then a pattern matching is applied to it:

```
if (temp6.$isInstanceOf[Main$Pair]())
{
  <synthetic> val temp7: Main$Pair = temp6.$asInstanceOf[Main$Pair]();
    new Tuple2(temp7.x(), temp7.y())
}
else
  throw new MatchError(temp6)
```

But nontheless this shouldn't compile imho. You should post this to the scala mailing list.

Comment: It's good to know, but I don't think the common supertype of `Product` is why it compiles.  I changed my example to show this, although they both still have a common super type of `Any`!